# Update package installed from git in Yarn 3

Tags: yarnpkg-v3

How to update a proprietary dependency installed from Git repo with Yarn 3?

`package.json` entry:

```
"@foo/utils": "git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-...:...@gitlab.com/foo/bar.git#ISSUE-6652-some-git-branch",
```

`yarn up @foo/utils` results in the following error:

```
➤ YN0027: @foo/utils@git+https://gitlab+deploy-token-...:...@gitlab.com/foo/bar.git#ISSUE-6652-some-git-branch can't be resolved to a satisfying range

Internal Error: The remote server failed to provide the requested resource
```

I need to update the package to latest commit in that branch and the only way I currently know is removing entry for this package manually from `yarn.lock`, but I guess that's not how things should be done.

Comment: same issue, I can only upgrade the package by typing the whole URLs, like `yarn up xxx@git+ssh://xxxxxxx#branch`

Answer (score 2):

It's not ideal since it's interactive, but you can run `yarn up -i @foo/utils` and choose "reuse" to force the package to resolve (and reinstall) from the same git source again.